# JS Creating Dynamic generateItems Not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have minimal code for this question but I'm hoping it's something simple that I am missing. What I am trying to do is to create three individual drag and drop boxes with a dynamic array. This is the array:

```
const col2 = ["Restoration Events", "Spectrum Utilization", "Segment Utilization"]
```

and here the code from this.state that is generating the three items:

```
items2: generateItems(3, (i) => ({ id: '2' + i, data: col2 }))
```

This code initially was:

```
items2: generateItems(1, (i) => ({ id: '2' + i, data: `Card 2 - ${i}`}))
```

which generated three boxes with a generic Card 2 + number, which is not what we are needing. I'm hoping there is something simple I am missing that will allow me to do this. Please forgive the limited code and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide code for `generateItems` function. There is not enough code to understand what's happening. Plus, the expected behavior.

Comment: `Card 2 - ${i}` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's kind of hard to understand what you want to achieve and what the context is.
I'll try to guess what you want to achieve and maybe that will help you.
Since I have not enough reputation I unfortunately cannot use the comment function.

Most probably you are developing a React-Component (because you are referring to `this.state`) and you somewhere found the code

```
constructor(props){

    ...

    this.state = {
        items2: generateItems(1, (i) => ({ id: '2' + i, data: `Card 2 - ${i}` }))
    }

    ...

}
```

Since you did not provide code for `generateItems` I can only guess that it may generate some object and incorporates the output from given inline function somehow.
My impression is, that you wanted to change it a way that the `data:` key will have one value from your array based on the index.

You could achieve this in the following way, but keep in mind that I did not take the function `generateItems` into consideration because the code is missing.

```
    ...
    const col2 = ["Restoration Events", "Spectrum Utilization", "Segment Utilization"]

    this.state = {
        items2: generateItems(3, (i) => ({ id: '2' + i, data: col2[i] }))
    }

    ...
```

This might point you in the right direction if my guess is correct, but you have
to provide more details. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.